# Android fetch json and form a list

Tags: android

I'm a new android user. I have a mysql database with a php script that returns a json http://localhost/FindIt/all_items.php

```
    [  
       {  
          "id":"1",
          "name":"Mukisa Ivan",
          "title":"Makerere University ID",
          "description":"This is a lost a ID picked at night near Olympia Hostel Gate",
          "date":"2017-05-01",
          "reward":"10,000",
          "location":"Makerere Kikoni",
          "photo":"",
          "category":"Id",
          "type":"Found",
          "userId":"1",
          "email":"mukisa@gmail.com",
          "phone":"+256706330511",
          "userType":"Founder"
       },
       {  
          "id":"3",
          "name":"Kalule Tom",
          "title":"UACE Results Slip",
          "description":"Lost My UACE results slip in areas of Wandegeya",
          "date":"2017-03-07",
          "reward":"5,000",
          "location":"Wandegeya",
          "photo":"",
          "category":"Document",
          "type":"Lost",
          "userId":"2",
          "email":"ktom@gmail.com",
          "phone":"+256706330511",
          "userType":"Loser"
       }
    ]
```

I want to fetch the above data and form a list in a fragment as below:-

```
    package com.example.kenneth.lostfound;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment2.
         */
        public static Fragment2 newInstance() {
            return new Fragment2();
        }

        public Fragment2() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment2, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_refresh){
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);

            String[] lostItemArray = {
                    "National ID - UCU Main Gate - 20/2/2016",
                    "UACE Results slip - Kampala Rd Taxi - 23/2/2016",
                    "Driving Permit - Ham Towers Makerere- 10/2/2016",

            };

            List<String> lost_items = new ArrayList<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(lostItemArray)
            );

            ArrayAdapter<String> mLostFoundAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_lostfound,
                    R.id.list_item_lostfound,
                    lost_items
            );

            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(
                    R.id.listview_lostfound
            );
            listView.setAdapter(mLostFoundAdapter);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

I want fetch data from `json` to update the list, or populate it in the list View element. I am using android studio 2.3

Comment: First of all use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) or any other ways to communicate server over Http such as [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) , [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit), [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) and also make async calls for preventing from `NetworkOnMainThreadException` . Then use any converter such as [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert Json to your Pojo class

Answer (score 0):

You can use any network library like `Volley`,`Retrofit` to fetch the json response from the server.

Herewith I am providing link for volley sample and retrofit sample.

1. Volley

   [Volley sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36907118/1501864)

   [Volley library to handle to webservice](https://github.com/Jeevs2nan/VolleyLibrary)
2. Retrofit

   [Retrofit sample](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

Coming to json parsing also there are some library which is used to fast parsing `Logan Square`, `gson`

1. [Logan Square](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare)

   2.[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Hope this is helpful:)