# How to HTTP POST in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-networking, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to do a HTTP POST in Android studio using with to retrieve values. I have already tested the thing in POSTMAN but I'm unsure of how to type it in Android studio. Please assist me in creating the HTTP POST Code for this.

**i'm doing a POST to**

```
ml2.internalpositioning.com/track
```

**with this body**

```
{"username":"fyp","location":"location","group":"cowardlycrab","time":1501640084739,"wifi-fingerprint":[{"mac":"04:c5:a4:66:43:7k","rssi":-29}]}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457492/how-do-i-use-the-simple-http-client-in-android

Comment: @Héctor if I that answer where do I put the body that I use in the POSTMAN?

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer. When we link something you should read the entire thing.

Comment: I do not understand the code for the 2nd answer that well, thats why I made that comment. Sorry @csm_dev

Comment: Instead of using HttpPost you can go for network libararies, which I have explained in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45210317/1501864. These libraries will make your work easier and faster than the http post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //call asynctask  like below : 

JSONObject post_dict = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        post_dict.put("username", "your_username_data");
 post_dict.put("location", "your_location_data");
 post_dict.put("group", "your_group_data");
 post_dict.put("time", "your_time_data");

JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jonj = new JSONObject();
jonj.put("mac","your_mac_data");
jonj.put("rssi","your_rssi_data");
jarr.put(jonj);
post_dict.put("wifi-fingerprint", jarr);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    new YourAsyncTask().execute(String.valueOf(post_dict));



//Actual Async Task Class 

      public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                        "Please Wait...",
                        "Registering Device");
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String JsonResponse = null;
                String JsonDATA = params[0];
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("ml2.internalpositioning.com/track");
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    // is output buffer writter
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    //set headers and method
                    Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(JsonDATA);
                    // json data
                    writer.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    //input stream
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        return null;
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                        return null;
                    }
                    JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
                    //response data
                    try {
                    //send to post execute
                        return JsonResponse;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (final IOException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (progressDialog != null)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
               //Do something with result
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i also try to send a http post.
I take the code from above
and change it for my case.
But unfortunately there is something wrong.

I want to send Date to my Yamaha AV Receiver RX-A1080.
There is a Web Interface and with this I record the HTTP POST Command
in Firefox Browser.
The Firefox Browser delivers also the data in a compact CURL command syntax so
you see better the data of the HTTP POST command in the following lines:

```
(as a CURL Command)
curl 
'http://192.168.0.24/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0' 
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' 
--compressed 
-H 'Referer: http://192.168.0.24/Setup/' 
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><YAMAHA_AV cmd="PUT"><System><Speaker_Preout><Pattern_1><PEQ><Manual_Data><Front_L><Band_7><Q>0.500</Q></Band_7></Front_L></Manual_Data></PEQ></Pattern_1></Speaker_Preout></System></YAMAHA_AV>'
```

i convert that with: https://curl.trillworks.com/#json
and get this:

```
{
"url":"http://192.168.0.24/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl",
"raw_url":"http://192.168.0.24/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl",
"method":"post",
"headers":
{
   "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) 
    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0",
   "Accept":"*/*",
   "Accept-Language":"de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
   "Referer":"http://192.168.0.24/Setup/",
   "Content-Type":"text/xml",
   "Connection":"keep-alive"
},
"data":
{
   "<?xml version":"\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><YAMAHA_AV cmd=\"PUT\"> 
<System><Speaker_Preout><Pattern_1><PEQ><Manual_Data><Front_L><Band_7><Q>0.500</Q></Band_7></Front_L></Manual_Data></PEQ></Pattern_1></Speaker_Preout></System></YAMAHA_AV>"
}
}
```

The Code i was written was that:
( i am not sure if there are to many slashes in JSONObject data ??? )

```
    // Gesamt JSON Object
    JSONObject post_dict = new JSONObject();

    try {
        post_dict.put("url", "http://192.168.0.24/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl");
        post_dict.put("raw_url", "http://192.168.0.24/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl");
        post_dict.put("method", "post");

        // headers - JSON Object ////////////////////////////////////////////

        JSONObject headers = new JSONObject();
        headers.put("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0");
        headers.put("Accept","*/*");
        headers.put("Accept-Language","de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
        headers.put("Referer","http://192.168.0.24/Setup/");
        headers.put("Content-Type","text/xml");
        headers.put("Connection","keep-alive");

        post_dict.put("headers", headers);

        // data - JSON Object ////////////////////////////////////////////

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("<?xml version","\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"utf-8\\\"?><YAMAHA_AV cmd=\\\"PUT\\\"><System><Speaker_Preout><Pattern_1><PEQ><Manual_Data><Front_L><Band_7><Gain><Val>-200</Val><Exp>1</Exp><Unit>dB</Unit></Gain></Band_7></Front_L></Manual_Data></PEQ></Pattern_1></Speaker_Preout></System></YAMAHA_AV>");

        post_dict.put("data", data);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new YourAsyncTask().execute(String.valueOf(post_dict));
```

Could somebody say me whats wrong :-(

For more Information of the recorded command done by Firefox
you can see the following lines. (But they are similiar to the CURL Command)

```
New Request
============
POST http://192.168.0.24/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl

Request-Header:
===============
Host: 192.168.0.24
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept: */*  
        Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
        Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
        Referer: http://192.168.0.24/Setup/
        Content-Type: text/xml
        Content-Length: 272
        Connection: keep-alive

Request-Body:
=============
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<YAMAHA_AV cmd="PUT">
    <System>
        <Speaker_Preout>
            <Pattern_1>
                <PEQ>
                    <Manual_Data>
                        <Front_L>
                            <Band_7>

                                <Gain>
                                    <Val>-10</Val>
                                    <Exp>1</Exp>
                                    <Unit>dB</Unit>
                                </Gain>
                         or
                                <Freq>1.26 kHz</Freq>
                         or
                                <Q>0.500</Q>

                            </Band_7>
                        </Front_L>
                    </Manual_Data>
                </PEQ>
            </Pattern_1>
        </Speaker_Preout>
    </System>
</YAMAHA_AV>
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that my data is not a json object.
I only have to send the "data" as a string.
Then it works ;-)